# Как поменять ширину блока

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Добавляю slick.js на сайт. Как мне поменять ширину этого блока? Что я только не пробовал. Карточка товара находится в левой части блока .slick-slide. Куда копать?

[image: Ширина]

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто, у вас элемент товара имеет ширину 25% .col-md-3 в views-column говорит об этом.
Я даже больше скажу, вы просто на странице товара создали список товаров по 4 в ряд и потом, когда нужно было блок карусель сделать - тупо скопировали и вставили в slick.
И даже не приходит да в голову, что работает bootstrap во всю))